# Shadow Incorrect at Bottom of Edge

Tags: light, lighting, shadows

In the images below, I have a cube that is sticking up about two thirds through a plane. But, despite the fact that the cube is not hovering over the plane, the shadow seems to indicate otherwise. How can I fix this shadow?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use *'contact shadows'* (Eevee) in the lamp settings:

[image]

Comment: Wow ...why isn't this the default setting?

Comment: I don't know... maybe because Eevee is designed for speed and that adds calculations.

Comment: It's not a default setting because *contact shadows* are view dependent. It can sometimes cause more problems like [light bleed](https://youtu.be/2VNztZdfGZY?t=586) from outside of the camera frame :).

Comment: thanks for the information, @JachymMichal.